# Programs listening to mouse don't react to programmatical mouse movement

Tags: c#, mouse

Title says it all; I have written a program which moves my mouse around on the screen. 
            `this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(list[i].X(), list[i].Y());`
but it seems like programes like games and my corsair macro recorder (Corsair Utility Engine) wont respond to that. Is there any way to fix that so that those applications pick up the movements?? Thanks (C#)

Comment: They may not be using Windows Message Pump to listen to mouse events and may be looking lower level, which is why they aren't working. I'm not sure how you can fake it out even lower level unless you create a fake mouse driver and use that to make position updates, maybe somebody else has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning the `Cursor.Position` property changes the cursor position directly.  That does not generate the input events that these kind of programs hook with a low-level mouse hook, the kind of events that are generated when the mouse driver notifies the operating system of a change in the mouse position.

You must [pinvoke SendInput()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html) instead.  It simulates the same kind of input that the mouse driver generates.  Almost surely makes that macro recorder come to life.  But not a guarantee that games can see it, they tend to use raw input to bypass game cheats. A very effective bypass.